# Unable to load configuration from uwsgi

Tags: nginx, debian, python, uwsgi

Since yesterday I have been wrestling with this problem: unable to load configuration from uwsgi

When I google it, nothing comes up. I am trying to run UWSGI under nginx with a very simple uwsgi.ini file. The file is being pointed to correctly.

Can anyone please explain what this error is, and how I ca go about diagnosing it and fixing it. If there is any more information I can post to help then please just ask.

Regards,

James

Comment: Please post the `uwsgi.ini` and the uwsgi logs

Comment: I had the same error, and I didn't have a "application" object in my Python file, as this is the default that uwsgi searches for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try running uwsgi manually to check that your ini file is correct or not,

```
uwsgi --ini myconf.ini --http :9090 --log-to /tmp/uwsgi.log
tail -f /tmp/uwsgi.log
```

You can try access the app (something like localhost:9090). There shoud be something write to the log file. If uwsgi itself works fine then the problem might be at nginx configuration.

Reference:

- http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#ini-files
- http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html

Comment: `--log-to` should read `--logto`